# The form of the subgroup of a finite abelian $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G\cong \Bbb{Z}_{p^{r_1}}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{p^{r_2}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{r_s}}$ be a finite abelian $p$-group, where $r_1\geq r_2\geq \cdots \geq r_s\geq 1$.
Let $H\cong \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_1}}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_2}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_u}}$ be a subgroup of $G$,
where $t_1\geq t_2\geq \cdots \geq t_u\geq 1$.

Prove that $s\geq u$ and $r_i\geq t_i$ for each $i=1, 2, ..., u$.

It seems obviously. But I just can't prove it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you can get the $s\geqslant u$ by considering the dimension of the natural $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector spaces $V:=\{x\in G|px=0\}$, $U:=\{x\in H|px=0\}$. And I think that passing to $pG$, $pH$ may help with the indices.

Comment: @ancientmathematician did you mean that use induction on $n$ for the second part, where $|G|=p^n$?

Comment: @bhafa: induction of $|G|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lemma II.2.5 in Hungerford's Algebra,
$$H[p]=\overbrace{\Bbb{Z}_p\oplus \cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_p}^{u\text{ times}}$$
is a subgroup of
$$G[p]=\overbrace{\Bbb{Z}_p\oplus \cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_p}^{s\text{ times}}$$
Note that both are elementary abelian group.
View them as $\Bbb{Z}$-module.
Since $G[p]$ and $H[p]$ are annihilated by the ideal $\langle p\rangle$ in $\Bbb{Z}$,
we can view $G[p]$ and $H[p]$ as vector space over $\Bbb{Z}/\langle p\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}_p$.
(See Example (5) in page 338 in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra.)
Hence, $H[p]$ is a subspace of $G[p]$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$
and $u=\dim_{\Bbb{Z}_p}H[p]\leq \dim_{\Bbb{Z}_p}G[p]=s$.

Now, we can write $H\cong \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_1}}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_2}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_u}}\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_{u+1}}}\oplus \cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_s}}$,
where $t_{u+1}=\cdots =t_s=0$.
Suppose that $r_j<t_j$ for some $j\in \{1, 2, ..., s\}$.
In this case,
by Lemma II.2.5 again,
$$p^{r_j}H\cong \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_1-r_j}}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_2-r_j}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{t_j-r_j}}$$
is a subgroup of
$$p^{r_j}G\cong \Bbb{Z}_{p^{r_1-r_j}}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{p^{r_2-r_j}}\oplus\cdots \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{p^{r_{j-1}-r_j}}.$$
Which is impossible because the length of $p^{r_j}H$ is greater than $p^{r_j}G$.

Comment: As the proof (i)$\Rightarrow$(iv) of Theorem II.1.1 in Hungerford's _Algebra_,
we have a commutative diagram
\begin{align}
X & \stackrel{\iota}{\rightarrow}  & F  \\
  & \searrow & \downarrow \overline{f}\\
  &          & G
\end{align}
where $F$ is a free abelian group of rank $s$.
Consider $\overline{f}^{-1}(H)\leq F$.
By Theorem II.1.6,
$\overline{f}^{-1}(H)$ is also a free abelian group of rank $u\leq s$.

Comment: Suppose that $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_u\}$ is a basis of $\overline{f}^{-1}(H)$.
By Theorem II.1.6 again,
there is a basis $\{d_1 y_1, d_2 y_2, ..., d_w y_w\}$ for the kernel of the homomorphism $\overline{f}|_{\overline{f}^{-1}(H)}$,
where $w\leq u$.

Comment: By First Isomorphism Theorem,
\begin{eqnarray*}
H
&\stackrel{\overline{f}\text{ is onto}}{=}& \overline{f}(\overline{f}^{-1}(H))
=\text{Im }\overline{f}|_{\overline{f}^{-1}(H)}
\cong \overline{f}^{-1}(H)/\ker{\overline{f}|_{\overline{f}^{-1}(H)}}\\
&\cong& \frac{\overbrace{y_1 \Bbb{Z}\oplus y_2 \Bbb{Z}\oplus \cdots \oplus y_u \Bbb{Z}}^{u \text{ times}}}{\underbrace{d_1 y_1 \Bbb{Z}\oplus d_2 y_2 \Bbb{Z}\oplus \cdots \oplus d_w y_w\Bbb{Z}}_{w \text{ times}}}
\cong \Bbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus \Bbb{Z}_{d_2}\oplus \cdots \oplus  \Bbb{Z}_{d_w}\oplus \Bbb{Z} \oplus \cdots,
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: where $d_1\mid d_2\mid \cdots \mid d_w$.
Since $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$,
it must be $w=u$.
Since $H$ is a subgroup of a $p$-group $G$,
it must be $d_1=p^{t_1}, d_2=p^{t_2}, ..., d_w=d_u=p^{t_u}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Count how many elements of order $p^d$ there are in each of $G$ and $H$, for each $d\in\mathbb{N}$.  Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the count for $H$ must be less than or equal to the count for $G$.

Comment: Could you please give me a little more hint or reference?

Comment: I think that $d$ can't be arbitrary.
For example, $H\cong \Bbb{Z}_4\oplus \Bbb{Z}_4\leq \Bbb{Z}_8\oplus \Bbb{Z}_2$.
I think that your idea is suppose that there is $r_j<t_j$ for some $j$.
Then the number of elements of order $p^d$ in $H$ is greater than in $G$ for some $d$.